# Java inheritance using super keyword

Tags: java, inheritance, super

I am using inheritance along with super function in my program ,but when I am extending my class it showing error message "There is no default constructor in 'cc'. " . This error message is coming after 1st subclass is extended and trying to make 2nd subclass. Here is the code

```
class aa{
int i=-1;
int show(){
return i;
}
} 
class bb extends aa{ 
 int i;
 bb(int g,int j){
 super.i=g;
 i=j;
 }
}

class cc extends bb {   
int j,k;
cc(int i, int j,int k) {
  super(i,j);
  super.i=i;
  this.j=j;
  this.k=k;
  }
}
 class dd extends cc{   // here the error showing 
 int h;                //" There is no default constructor in 'cc' "
 void hello(){
 System.out.println("hello");
 }
}
class SuperUseExample3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        aa x = new aa();
        System.out.println("value of a = "+x.i);
        bb y = new bb(8,2);
        System.out.println("value of a in class cc = "+y.show());
        System.out.println("value of b in class bb = "+y.i);
        cc z =new cc(12,13,14);
        System.out.println("value of a in class cc = "+z.show());
        System.out.println("value of b in class cc = "+z.j);
        System.out.println("value of c in class cc = "+z.k);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dd` inherits `cc`, so it'll have to call the default constructor of `cc`, which currently doesn't exist.

To solve this, just add a constructor with no arguments

```
class cc extends bb {   
    int j,k;
    cc(){
        //do whatever you want
    }
    ..//rest of code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are extending class cc in dd. But in dd you are not initialising anything which cc possess and that is the error, because when dd is called it is searching for a constructor of its superclass and when no constructor is defined java takes a without parameter constructor as default. So it call that parameter in cc but you have not defined any blank parameter in cc so it is saying it has only **1** constructor and you need to create other blank constructor.

Answer (score 0):

`cc` class constructor is

```
cc(int i, int j,int k) {
}
```

therefore, you need to call `super(i, j, k)` in `dd`. For example:

```
 class dd extends cc{   
   int h;                
   dd(int i, int j,int k) {
     super(i, j, k);
   }
   void hello(){
     System.out.println("hello");
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `cc` class has a single constructor that takes arguments:

```
cc(int i, int j, int k) {}
```

If you want to inherit from `cc`, you must:

- Either call `super(int i, int j, int k)` in your `dd` constructor to call `cc`'s constructor, passing the arguments required by the constructor.
- Or create a default constructor for `cc` that takes no argument: `cc() {}`. If you don't call `super()`, this constructor would be called by default.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that dd extends cc, that has a constructor of cc(int i, int j, int k), but dd's constructor doesn't calls it.
You need to add a constructor to dd that calls super(i, j, k).

Example code for dd:

```
}
class dd extends cc{
dd(int i, int j, int k) {
super(i, j, k);
}
int h;
void hello(){
System.out.println("hello");
}
```